# Retrofit HEAD must use Void as Response Type in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit

I have the following API method defined:

```
@HEAD("test/{name})
fun checkTitle(@Path("name") name: String): Single<Response<Void>>
```

I then want to unit test a successful response on this HEAD request but can't figure out how to instantiate a Void object in Kotlin.

```
whenever(mockService.checkTitle(any()))
    .thenReturn(Single.just(Response.success(*VOID NEEDS TO BE HERE*)))

repo.checkTitle("tester")
    .test()
    .assertError(ValueTaken::class.java)
```

If I change the api call response to return Unit, it crashes at runtime with the following error as Retrofit does not support Unit yet.

> HEAD method must use Void as response type.

**EDIT** - Addition of classes tried so far

I have tried the following so far but the compiler complains saying that it is expecting a return type of `Single<Response<Void>>!`

- Unit
- Nothing
- Any
- null

Comment: have you tried with **`Any`** type?

Comment: Yes unfortunately that is not acceptable for `Void`

Comment: Void is null. Can you pass in null if you change the type to `Void?`? Perhaps `Nothing?` translates to Java Void as the only possible value for both is null.

Comment: @EugenPechanec sorry I should have said what I have tried already. I have added it to my initial question.

Comment: shouldn't this `@HEAD(""test/{name})` be like `@HEAD("/test/{name}")`

Comment: Thanks, I have removed the invalid quotation marks (this was just an error when I input it into stack overflow). However my base url contains the preceding `/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an instance of `Void` through the (ab)use of reflection:

```
val voidConstructor = Void::class.java.getDeclaredConstructors()[0]
voidConstructor.setAccessible(true)
val voidInstance = voidConstructor.newInstance()
```

What this is doing is:

- getting the first declared constructor for `Void`, which is private
- setting it to public
- creating an instance from that constructor

While I wouldn't suggest this in production code, in testing this is more palatable.

Comment: Whilst I don't like the idea of using reflection in production code like you say, in a test it should be ok. Thanks for the solution. I will wait a few days before accepting in case someone comes up with a cleaner solution.

Comment: FYI I also had to case it as Void like so: `voidInstance as Void`

Comment: Yep, I’d also like to see a cleaner solution! Thanks for the edit, missed that error in my early morning posting.

Answer (score 0):

The issue might stem from wrapping with `Single` (is that RxJava?),
because [it](https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/108fe23964b986107aed352ba467cd2007d15208/retrofit/src/main/java/retrofit2/HttpServiceMethod.java#L76) only checks for `!Void.class.equals(responseType)`:

```
if (responseType == Response.class) {
  throw methodError(method, "Response must include generic type (e.g., Response<String>)");
}

// TODO support Unit for Kotlin?
if (requestFactory.httpMethod.equals("HEAD") && !Void.class.equals(responseType)) {
  throw methodError(method, "HEAD method must use Void as response type.");
}
```

---

Therefore it might be easier to use `Call<Void>` & `Response<Void>` (without any `ResponseBody` or other ORM mapping class). With `@HEAD` there won't be a `ResponseBody` anyway and instancing `Void` seems strange to me (as this data-type definition is barely used for delivering and eventually mapping the response). Regular co-routines eg. with `suspend` might play along better (because the data-type does not need to be wrapped). For comparison, in Java this is straightforward:

```
@HEAD Call<Void> checkTitle(@Path(value = "name") String name);
```